# MySQL query for similar videos via video tagging (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, video, tags

I am working on a PHP application wich includes a video section. I have so far constructed video tagging as an video categorization. When you are adding a video, you can select from 25 predefined tags ones wich describes your video content best.

These tags are then saved in a separate table, `videotags`, that looks like this:

```
video_id | first_tag | second_tag | third_tag | etc.
----------------------------------------------------
     123 |         1 |          0 |          1| ...
```

So that means, when you check in the form some tag, it is stored as 1 in database, unchecked as 0.

Now when you view a video, you can see a main body, where video and description is, and a right column, where similar videos should be.

I would like to build a MySQL query that will return 6 similar videos, based on video tags with a rule like this:

**Those videos, wich have the most same video tags as viewed video, will be ordered and limited to 6.**

For example, I am trying to view a video with ID 12, that has six filled tags, and in my database I have 3 videos:

- Video with ID 22 that has 7 tags and 4 are same as video with ID 12.
- Video with ID 25 that has 8 tags and 5 are the same as ID 12 video.
- Video with ID 45 that has 4 tags and 3 are the same as ID 12 video.

As I have mentioned in topic name, I am building this PHP application in CodeIgniter, so this query will run in a specific model as a function, I am going to pass in this function the array `$tags` like this `$tags['first_tag'] = 1`.

Can anyone help me build this query as specified? I am working with Active Record Class in CI, so using it would be appriciated.

Thanks guys for respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look something like this one:

```
SELECT video_id 
FROM videotags 
ORDER BY ABS(
  first_tag - 1 +
  second_tag - 0
) ASC
LIMIT 3
```

And in ActiveRecord function would look something like this:

```
function getTop($n, $tags) {
  $this->db->select('video_id');
  $order = array();
  foreach ($tags as $field => $value) {
    if ($value) {
      $order[] = $field .' - '. $value;
    }
  }
  $this->db->order_by('ABS('.implode(' + ', $order).')', 'ASC');
  return $this->db->get('videotags', $n);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested it. Also the query will be rather slow for many rows.

Comment: Thank you, it's working great! I just had to send there only non-zero tags, and change 'DESC' to 'ASC'. You have my deepest thanks, AquillaX.